# Unity Unit Tests fail, but GitLab CI pipeline job passes (shell executor)

Tags: unity-game-engine, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm gobsmacked by this issue I'm having with implementing continuous integration into my Unity project.

I downloaded the Gitlab CI Runner and registered my desktop PC as a specific runner to my project. I set the executor to `shell` and set up no tags for my runner.

I then wrote a simple test which contains a single line saying `Assert.Fail()`. If I go into Unity > Window > General > Test Runner and run my test - It fails:
[image: it fails]

I then added a `gitlab-ci.yml` to my project:

```
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

unit-test:
  script: 
    - echo testing ; & "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.1.4f1\Editor\Unity.exe" -batchmode -projectPath "C:\workspace\automatedtesting\Simple Lane Runner" -runTests -testPlatform editmode -testResults "C:\workspace\automatedtesting\testresults\results.xml" -logFile "C:\workspace\automatedtesting\testresults\logfile.log"
  stage: test
```

If I run the line on `script` locally my computer gets a little busy, echoes 'testing'. If I then go to my `logfile.log` or my `results.xml` I can see they've just been created, and contain information saying my test has failed.

However, the pipeline job just simply succeeds. It throws no errors whatsoever.

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.6.0 (8fa89735)
  on Kamiel-Desktop-Runner 69UDXkRe
Resolving secrets
00:00
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on DESKTOP-ONQCMQA...
Getting source from Git repository
00:02
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/GitLab-Runner/builds/69UDXkRe/0/visserk18/automatedtesting/.git/
Checking out 7a897989 as master...
git-lfs/2.10.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.12.7; git a526ba6b)
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:08
$ echo testing ; & "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.1.4f1\Editor\Unity.exe" -batchmode -projectPath "C:\workspace\automatedtesting\Simple Lane Runner" -runTests -testPlatform editmode -testResults "C:\workspace\automatedtesting\testresults\results.xml" -logFile "C:\workspace\automatedtesting\testresults\logfile.log"
testing
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded
```

Am I missing something here? Shouldn't this job fail as soon as it comes across a failed test..? Wherever I look, (for example in this guide: https://engineering.etermax.com/continuous-integration-in-unity-with-gitlab-ci-cd-part-1-e902c94c0847 or other 'Example unity projects' I can find on github ) I see nothing else happening other than what I've got in my `.yml`. Am I overseeing something?

Comment: I think using the call symbol doesn't necessarily catch the output. Have you tried running without the 'echo' or the '&' ?

Comment: I have tried it without the `echo`, without the echo the .yml file will be marked as invalid. If I leave out the & too, it will also mark the syntax as invalid.

Comment: You can add : `before_script: $env:Path = $env:Path + ";C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.1.4f1\Editor\"` to your `gitlab-ci.yml` then you should be able to call `Unity.exe` directly with no `&` or path.

Comment: That's a good note, thanks. What I eventually ended up doing was moving my project and unity editor to directories which don't contain any spaces, removing the need for strings entirely. But I agree that that's a bit of a botch :)

Answer (score 1):

OK Solved!

So the output of a Gitlab CI job is equal to that of the output of the exit code of the program you're running. The problem being that just running this line failed to return the proper exit code.

The solution was to create a new PowerShell script, which runs the unity line and then stores it's exit code into a variable. We then exit with unity's exit code in mind:

```
& "C:\UnityEditors\2020.1.17f1\Editor\Unity.exe" -batchMode -projectPath . -runTests -logFile .\unitTests.log -testResults .\unitTests.xml | Tee-Object -FilePath .\runner.log
$UNITYCODE = $LastExitCode
Exit $UNITYCODE
```

We will store this script in `<root of git repo>\CIScripts` as `runTests.ps1`

Now the gitlab-ci.yml can be altered to just run the powershell script, which will then return the unity exit code:

```
stages:
  - test

unit-test:
  script: 
    - CIScripts/runTests.ps1
  stage: test
```

My pipeline job now fails when my Test contains `Assert.Fail()` and passes when the tests pass! Hurray!

We can now also write seperate powershell scripts for the build/deploy phase, and call them accordingly.

**EDIT:** Another, simpler solution is to add `| Out-Default` at the end of the unity line.

For example, this gitlab-ci.yml will test and pass/fail my pipeline job correctly:

```
stages:
  - test

unit-test:
  script: 
    - C:\UnityEditors\2020.1.17f1\Editor\Unity.exe -batchMode -projectPath . -runTests -logFile .\unitTests.log -testResults .\unitTests.xml | Out-Default
  stage: test
```