# I am stuck trying to let GitLab CI run a shell file that builds Unity Player. It works when I do it but not when GitLab Tries it

Tags: shell, unity-game-engine, gitlab, gitlab-ci

## The Problem

I used a tutorial to create a shell file that would build an Unity player for me. [Tutorial I used](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2v9BLSG02Go). But when I try to let GitLab's CI call this shell script it seems only clean-up the directory and just ignore the Unity build command. [Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2btx.png)

My .yml file looks like this: (Important is the build-job: section all the other stuff works)

```yaml
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build
  - test

build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code..."
    - ./Build/build.sh
    - echo "Compile complete."

unit-test-job:   # This job runs in the test stage.
  stage: test    # It only starts when the job in the build stage completes successfully.
  script:
    - echo "Running unit tests... This will take about 60 seconds."
    - C:/"Program Files"/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.20f1/Editor/Unity.exe \
        -batchmode \
        -projectPath C:/Users/joshu/Desktop/Gamedev/Testing/testing-asignment-2/"Testing_Asignment 2" \
        -runTests -testPlatform editmode \
        -logFile . \
        -testResults ./unit-tests.xml \
        -quit
    - echo "Code is tested"

lint-test-job:   # This job also runs in the test stage.
  stage: test    # It can run at the same time as unit-test-job (in parallel).
  script:
    - echo "Linting code... This will take about 10 seconds."
    - echo "No lint issues found."
```

My shell script contains this:

```sh
echo Cleaning Up Build Folder
rm -rf ./Build/Builds

echo Starting Build Process
C:/"Program Files"/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.20f1/Editor/Unity.exe -quit -projectPath ../"Testing Asignment 2" -executeMethod Building.MyBuildScript.PreformBuild
echo Ended Build Process
```

My building script contains this:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Build.Reporting;

namespace Building
{
    public class MyBuildScript
    {
        public static void PreformBuild()
        {
            BuildPlayerOptions buildPlayerOptions = new BuildPlayerOptions();
            buildPlayerOptions.scenes = new[] { "Assets/Scenes/SampleScene.unity" };
            buildPlayerOptions.locationPathName = "../Build/Builds/WindowsBuild/Windows64Build.x86_64";
            buildPlayerOptions.target = BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows64;
            buildPlayerOptions.options = BuildOptions.None;
            BuildReport report = BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(buildPlayerOptions);

            using StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText("../Build/Builds/WindowsBuild/results.txt");
            writer.Write(
                $"Build result: {report.summary.result} \n" +
                $"Process time: \n" +
                $"              start: {report.summary.buildStartedAt} \n" +
                $"              end: {report.summary.buildEndedAt} \n" +
                $"              total: {report.summary.totalTime} \n" +
                $"{report.summary.totalErrors} Errors found{(report.summary.totalErrors > 0 ? "!" : "")}");
        }
    }
}
```

I think that there is some thing wrong with the access of my Unity.exe but when I open security settings on windows the excess to write/execute is enabled.

## Things I tried

I also tried just not using a shell script and calling the MyBuildScript from the .yml directly.

```yaml
build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code..."
    - C:/"Program Files"/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.20f1/Editor/Unity.exe -quit -projectPath ./"Testing Asignment 2" -executeMethod Building.MyBuildScript.PreformBuild
    - echo "Compile complete."
```

But this also seemed to not execute Unity and just skip the command.

Furthermore I tried using the -buildWindows64Player instead of the -executeMethod.

```yaml
build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code..."
    - C:/"Program Files"/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.20f1/Editor/Unity.exe -quit -projectPath ./"Testing Asignment 2" -buildWindows64Player ./Build/Builds/WindowsBuild
    - echo "Compile complete."
```

But this also seemed have skipped Unity. However this way of trying did take the longest to finish. All the other options were done in a few seconds but doing it like this it took about a minute or two. I don't know why but if I had to guess it would be because it actually did start-up Unity and failed somewhere on the way.

#### *Note*

I know that I should add -batchmode to the shell commands but first I want to see Unity open so that I know it is doing something.

Little update as of 12-29-2021 23:48. I noticed that the unit-test also wasn't realy working but I fixed this by changing my Unity version to 2021.2.7f1, changing the Unity project folder structure and updating the unit-test section to this:

```yaml
unit-test-job:   # This job runs in the test stage.
  stage: test    # It only starts when the job in the build stage completes successfully.
  script:
    - echo "Running unit tests... This will take about 60 seconds."
    - C:/"Program Files"/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.2.7f1/Editor/Unity.exe -batchmode -projectPath C:/Users/joshu/Desktop/Gamedev/Testing/testing-asignment-2/"Testing Asignment 2" -runTests -testPlatfrom editmode -logFile -testResults ./unit-tests.xml | Out-Default
```

Comment: You on unix or windows? Such a mix of stuff going on there with windows paths and forward slashes and .sh (usually unix based) what happens if you call your build.sh yourself?

Comment: Well I doubt that Gitlab CI has Unity installed under `C:/"Program Files"/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.20f1/Editor/Unity.exe` ;)

Comment: @BugFinder I am working on a windows device. and when I call build.sh myself it runs Unity just fine. Unity also builds the game when I run it myself.

Comment: @derHugo I thought since the runner is installed on my laptop I needed to provide the installation path of my laptop

Answer (score 0):

Well turns out I did something stupid. I had my runner installed on my laptop and kept trying to push new changes from my pc. However I used the projectPath that pointed to my local project on the laptop and not the project that the runner was cloning from GitLab. So the -projectPath now points to ./"Testing Asignment 2". This also was the reason I thought changing my Unity version helped because I pulled the project to my laptop while installing a new version.

I also discoverd that my test needed to have "| Out-Default" behind it to actually sort of read the test data. [StackOverflow page that helped with this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65218629/unity-unit-tests-fail-but-gitlab-ci-pipeline-job-passes-shell-executor)

I don't realy use the shell script anymore now but I just wanted it building Unity, and that works!
The .yml file I am using right now looks like this:

```yaml
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build
  - test

build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code..."
    - C:/"Program Files"/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.2.7f1/Editor/Unity.exe -batchmode -quit -projectPath ./"Testing Asignment 2" -executeMethod Building.MyBuildScript.PreformBuild | Out-Default
    - echo "Compile complete."

unit-test-job:   # This job runs in the test stage.
  stage: test    # It only starts when the job in the build stage completes successfully.
  script:
    - echo "Running unit tests... This will take about 60 seconds."
    - C:/"Program Files"/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.2.7f1/Editor/Unity.exe -batchmode -quit -projectPath ./"Testing Asignment 2" -runTests -testPlatfrom editmode -logFile -testResults ./unit-tests.xml | Out-Default
```

(I also changed my gitignore to not ignore Library\ScriptAssemblies from Unity. But I don't know if this is needed.)